# Snakemake: variable that defines whether process is submitted cluster job or the snakefile

Tags: snakemake

My current architecture is that at the start of my Snakefile I have a long running function `somefunc` which helps decide the "input" to `rule all`. I realized when I was running the workflow with slurm that `somefunc` is being executed by each job. Is there some variable I can access that defines whether the code is a submitted job or whether it is the main process:

```
if not snakemake.submitted_job:
    config['layout'] = somefunc()

...
```

Comment: Please provide more details (the Snakemake code). The fact is that the Snakemake script defines just the structure of the workflow, and you have a limited control of what would be executed in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with @dariober it seems the cleanest to check whether the (hidden) snakemake directory has locks since they seem not to be generated until the first rule starts (assuming you are not using the --nolock argument).

```
import os
locked = len(os.listdir(".snakemake/locks")) > 0
```

However this results in a problem in my case:

```
import time
import os


def longfunc():
    time.sleep(10)
    return range(5)

locked = len(os.listdir(".snakemake/locks")) > 0
if not locked:
    info = longfunc()


rule all:
    input:
        expand("test_{sample}", sample=info)



rule test:
    output:
        touch("test_{sample}")
    run:
        """
        sleep 1
        """
```

Somehow snakemake lets each rule reinterpret the complete snakefile, with the issue that all the jobs will complain that 'info is not defined'. For me it was easiest to store the results and load them for each job (pickle.dump and pickle.load).

Answer (score 1):

A solution which I don't really recommend is to make `somefunc` write the list of inputs to a tmp file so that slurm jobs will read this tmp file rather than reconstructing the list from scratch. The tmp file is created by whatever job is executed first so the long-running part is done only once.

At the end of the workflow delete the tmp file so that later executions will start fresh with new input.

Here's a sketch:

```
def somefunc():
    try:
        all_output = open('tmp.txt').readlines()
        all_output = [x.strip() for x in all_output]
        print('List of input files read from tmp.txt')
    except:
        all_output = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'] # Long running part
        with open('tmp.txt', 'w') as fout:
            for x in all_output:
                fout.write(x + '\n')
        print('List of input files created and written to tmp.txt')
    return all_output

all_output = somefunc()

rule all:
    input:
        all_output,

rule one:
    output:
        all_output,
    shell:
        r"""
        touch {output}
        """

onsuccess:
    os.remove('tmp.txt')
onerror:
    os.remove('tmp.txt')
```

Since jobs will be submitted in parallel, you should make sure that only one job writes `tmp.txt` and the others read it. I think the try/except above will do it but I'm not 100% sure. (Probably you want to use some better filename than `tmp.txt`, see the module [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html). see also the module [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html)) for exit handlers)

Comment: I was already afraid I would have to implement something 'hacky' like this. Your answer gave me an idea though. Maybe it would be best not to write to some file (e.g. tmp.txt), but to check whether the directory is locked or not. I just checked, and the locks are not generated until the first rule is started. (locks can be found in .snakemake/locks/)

Comment: Btw thanks for your suggestion! I'm leaving the question open for a couple of days, and will accept if nothing better will pop up.

Comment: I think your idea of looking at the locks is much better - Once you have something in place (and nothing better appears!) consider writing it is an answer...

Comment: Checking whether the locks exist or not works up to some extent. Snakemake will start the jobs normally, but these jobs then fail on rule all since the all_output variable is not defined properly. We can then of course wrap rule all inside another if statement...